# Convertir consulta SQL a DQL (doctrine)

Tags: sql, doctrine, dql

¿Cómo puedo convertir esta consulta SQL a DQL?

```
SELECT * FROM booking WHERE booking.Date > now()
```

Intente esto:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$result = $em->createQueryBuilder();

$dql = $result->select('b')
->from('AppBundle:Booking', 'b')
->where('b.Date > now()')
->getQuery();
```